# List of open browser tabs programmatically

Tags: python, browser, scripting, tabs

Is there a way to programmatically obtain a **list of open tabs in a browser** by index?

For example, suppose Google Chrome is open with two tabs.
In the program, a line something like:

```
tabs_list = list_tabs(hwnd)
```

...where hwnd is the handle to the window for the overall Chrome instance and tabs_list is a dictionary something like:

```
{
  0 : 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
  1 : 'http://www.otherstufff.com/'
}
```

(...or maybe by title of the window instead of url)

*If so, then bringing focus to one of them can be possible from the Python script with keyboard commands, control- (CTRL-) like control-1 or control-2.*

---

An edit added later to try to help clarify:  Picture a local wxPython app, where you already know how to activate a given instance of Chrome on that same box from within your wxPython app running locally, and that browser instance has multiple tabs open, and now you want to insure that a certain tab has focus, to be able to interact with that web page that is being displayed (maybe using CTRL-A CTRL-C for example to harvest its content).  This question is not about issuing keyboard commands, that is already known, the question is how to obtain a list of open tabs, if possible, thanks.

Comment: It will really help to know the platform (os).  I'm guessing from hwnd it's Windows but adding this detail (and tagging appropriately) would be essential in giving you an answer.

Comment: Did not specify OS because the goal is to develop a cross-platform application, however, if we need to limit it, starting with Windows.  Yet, do really appreciate your example for Mac OS X and the tip for OLE Automation with Python, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While not sure of your target OS, you can do this on Mac OS X:

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> map(lambda x: x.title(), app('Google Chrome').windows[0].tabs())
[u'Stack Overflow', u'Google']
```

On Windows, you will want to look into OLE Automation with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible. First you haven't noted what app you develop but if you use python for a website backend - then its just a server-side language and does not know what a "browser" is - the server outputs to the browser and thats all. And I don't believe it's possible with client-side language like javascript as this seem to be a serious security and privacy issue if it was possible.

Edit: If you are developing a Chrome plugin lets say it might be a whole different story - but then it goes towards the Chrome API and your tagging is wrong, as "python" itself can not do that.

Comment: Primarily Python, see note added to original question.  I do not necessarily think Python cannot do that, because Python can call Windows (for example) API's via ctypes, win32api and other modules, lots-o-fun.

Comment: I think he was talking about a desktop app.