# List currently open webpages in chrome using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have some webpages currently open in my chrome browser. I want to write a Python script to list link of open pages.

I found that the typing the following in chrome gives the list.

`chrome://inspect/#pages`

However, this is not a webpage and cannot be read using:

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('chrome://inspect/#pages')
page_content = page.read()
with open('page_content.html', 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content)
```

So, my question is how can I read `chrome://inspect/#pages` using Python?

Comment: No, as you said it does not exist, it's just an internal syntax of the chrome browser to access some internal status. You can try to see whether chrome has IPC mechanisms for this kind of stuff though.

Comment: There's a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537832/list-of-open-browser-tabs-programmatically) (with a working solution for OS X)