# How to get browser's active tabs URL using python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, firefox

I am trying to get the url of active tabs of Google Chrome and other browsers.

I have tried to open the session files of Mozilla Firefox but the output of the code is getting wrong.

```
import json
f = open(r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ad0v8pf6.defaul
t\sessionstore.js", "r")
jdata = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
print(str(jdata["windows"][0]["selected"]))
for win in jdata.get("windows"):
          for tab in win.get("tabs"):
                  i = tab.get("index") - 1
                  print(tab.get("entries")[i].get("url"))
```

The code returns number of current tabs that are open and their url, but I am getting output as 2 and two urls, but 5 tabs were open at that time.

I have also tried selenium but no progress.

Comment: What's the contents of `sessionstore.js`? Does it contain what you need? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: sir , it contains the information about the current tabs and their url

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645123/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-active-google-chrome-tab-in-windows or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537832/list-of-open-browser-tabs-programmatically

Comment: sessionstore just save that website who wants to save their own sessions!! for other website will not work! i recommend you to read about "what is website session" ...

Comment: Check out https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab